# How can I store image information in 2d array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to divide a color image into 100 blocks of equal size in matlab and then store the maximum color information present in the box in a 2d array of 10*10.

**Example:**

If the maximum color present in the block is

- black, then it should store 0
- white then 1,
- red then 2,
- ...

in the corresponding cell of 2d array.

I have finite number of colors in my image. I read an article on `blockproc` but I was unable to implement it.

How can I do this?

**EDIT: (code from comment)**

```
I=imread('Untitled.png'); 
I = I(1:290,1:288,:); 
[m n o] = size(I); 
r = m/240; 
c = n/240; 
fun = @(block_struct) max(block_struct.data(:)); 
J = blockproc(I,[r c],fun); 
imshow(J);
```

Comment: What do you call a maximum color?

Comment: what i did is given below....I=imread('Untitled.png');
I = I(1:290,1:288,:);
[m n o] = size(I);
r = m/240;
c = n/240;
fun = @(block_struct) max(block_struct.data(:));
J = blockproc(I,[r c],fun);
imshow(J);
now the problem i am facing is i am loosing color information in this kind of approach....i want 2 in J if the color is red the corresponding block,3 if it is blue and so on....i am doing this because i want to find the shortest distance between two objects in an image such that the path doesnt cover up a particular color,(say path should not cover up black portion of image)......

Comment: maximum color means maximum amount of color present in the block

Answer (score 0):

If you have a finite number of colors in your image you may convert it from 3D RGB image into an [*indexed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color) image by calling [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html):

```
 myColMap; % this is your color map: 
           % it should have black as its first entry, 
           % white in second, red in third etc.
 indImg = rgb2ind( I, myColMap ); % convert RGB image to indexed one
```

To find the most "popular" color in each patch (note this is not the `max` color, but rather the [`mode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mode.html))

```
 fun = @(block_Struct) mode( block_struct.data(:) )
 J = blockproc( indImg, [r c], fun );
```

Note that patch size `[r c]` should be an *integer* number. Therefore, if your image size is not dividable by `240` (as in your example) this might cause issues. Check `blockproc` parameters to assist you handling this condition.